# CSVGREP to subset a large dataset

Tags: python, csv, grep

I'm trying to subset a large datset using csvkit and am having trouble writing a new csv.

I have a 1.4 gb csv of all donations made during the 2012 election and am trying to subset this into only donations for either Obama or Romney.

The code I have thus far is this: csvgrep -c recipient_name -m obama,romney > presidential.csv

The command line seems to hang and a file is created, however, nothing is getting written. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Think this is a regex problem. Your regex isn't matching anything so you're scanning the file but not finding a single value.

You want:

```
csvgrep -c recipient_name -m obama|romney > presidential.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Malcom, but it seems that this isn't working either. I've tried regex as well with -r "obama"|"romney" as well as each separately, but nothing works.

Comment: Maybe try just -m obama to see if that works - could also be case Obama?